# How to Push A view with TabBarController as Root

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller

I'm starting out with iOS Development.

Currently, I've implemented a TabBarController that nests 2 Views, one of which has a TableView within in.

I'm trying to get the table view to Push another view when DidSelectRow is called.

What I am trying to do is similar to the **AppStore in the Search Tab.**
I.E:
When you find the App you want you tap on the table row - then the search bar fades away and the Navigation bar fades in, revealing more detail.

Right now I'm trying this:

```
self.nav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:rootVC];
nav.delegate = self;    
self.detailView = [[detailView alloc] initWithNibName:@"detailView" bundle:nil];

[nav pushViewController:self.detailView animated:YES];
```

Where rootVC is the viewController in my secondView.

This does nothing. I've called NSLog to make sure that the method is being called, and it is.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have a navigation controller in the app? One way to achieve the navigation controller with tab bar controller is to add navigation controller for each tab bar item . Then make the root view controller of the navigation controller one of your 2 views controllers.

Comment: I've tried to implement a UINavigationController, but everytime I alter the properties of TabView Button to the class NavController (which implements UINavigationController), all it returns is an empty NavController with a blue bar up the top. It calls viewDidLoad but I cant set the view to what I want it do be!

Comment: you don't alter the tabview button, If you had added the tabbar from nib you drag UINavigation controller and put on the tabbar controller. Till you see your window with both tabbar and navigation bar. Then you setup the navigation controller root view controller to your view controller.